# Why does sometimes, the visual studio loses a class reference?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

Sometimes, the reference of a method that it's on a static class, just disappeared. That means that it's not painted in the "green" color that's typical of a class, and i can't neither navigate trough this method(right click > go to definition)

Why is this happening?

thx.

Comment: Be clear, is it losing the type reference or the method reference?

Comment: What's the difference? let me explain myself better: It's a static class, that it contains a method inside. I'm trying to call it from another page, and it compiles with no issues, but sometimes i'm trying to navigate through withouth going to the solution explorer, i can't, because the class word itsn't painted green like it should be. When I hover on the class, it isn't showing me nothing, like it's a common word

Comment: OK, so it's not that it can't find the method, it simply can't resolve the class (at design time, but runtime executes fine?) Where is the class stored, in the `App_Code` folder?

Comment: yes. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Yeah I've come across this before. I would recommend extracting such code from your site project and put it in a class library anyway - never had such troubles with this approach. Is your project a web site or web application project type?

Comment: It's a web site. Right now i'm working on that, i'm also separating the js from aspx pages into .js files. I will try this, thanks a lot!

Comment: Hm, if it were a web application I might have suggested this was something to do with compilation not being done on the fly, not sure with a web site project. Anyway, yeah separate the code into projects, and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have something else closer to your scope (like a property) that has the same name.
The code editor won't go too much out of its way to guess whether the identifier is a type or a property.

Answer (score -1):

This usually happens if you open the file directly without opening the project. I have seen this happening when visual studio loads the source code for a class while debugging(single stepping through the code) for which the project is not loaded.

Comment: im not doing that, I open the entire solution and with it the project